# Get index of object in array onClick VUE3

Tags: arrays, vue.js, vuex, vuejs3

I've been struggling on this for hours !
I'm really new to vue, vuex...

What i'd like to do is pretty simple : i have multiples object in an array, i want on click, to get the index of the object, so i can later grab some info in that object.

- I click on an item on the list
- I got the index
- then, i got a function that will seek for infos (like myArr[index].values_.geometry.flatCoordiantes)

Here is my list :

```html
<ul id="features-list">
      <button
        v-for="(feature, index) in filterByTerm"
        :key="index"
        v-on:click="storeCoords($event, index)"
      >
        {{ feature.values_.name }} {{ index }}
      </button>
    </ul>
```

Here is my computed :

```js
computed: {
    listedFeatures() {
      return this.$store.getters.GET_ALLFEATURES;
    },
    filterByTerm() {
      return this.listedFeatures.filter((feature) => {
        return feature.values_.name
          .toLowerCase()
          .includes(this.searchInput.toLowerCase());
      });
    },
  },
```

Here is my method :

```js
 methods: {
    storeCoords(event) {
      // i'd like to access to coordinate of my object to inject it in another variable
      // this.filterByTerm[event.target.index].values_.coordiantes.etc...
      console.log(this.filterByTerm);

    },
  },
};
```

As you can see, i console.log filterByTerm, but i don't understand i get something like below :

```
(3) [Proxy, Proxy, Proxy]
0: Proxy
[[Handler]]: Object
[[Target]]: Feature
```

I really have no idea how i can get some infos in that [[ stuff ]] :s
And yes, my {{index}} is showing the actually index of current item.
If anyone could help, that would be really nice !

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the iterator object to your `click`-handler in the binding:

```html
<button v-on:click="storeCoords(feature, index)">
```

Then access the coordinates from the object argument:

```js
export default {
  methods: {
    storeCoords(feature, index) {
      // assuming the coordinates are stored in `coordinates` prop
      console.log(feature.coordinates)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks a lot for this clear answer, i had a little idea after i stopped working on that that if i can retrieve feature.values_.name i would probably be able to get anything else, but i missed the "feature"
I'll try see tomorrow thanks a lot anyway !

Comment: Ok so i can't get the console log but i guess it works :o

Comment: What do you mean by "can't get the console.log"?

Comment: nah it's ok, it was just me being noob at vue ! everything is fine :) thx !